# creating an object of arrays and values from an array of objects containing arrays and values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In the following code snippet, I am gathering variables from an array of objects and then combining them into a single new object with other variables. Here is a simplified example:

```js
var y = 10; 
var x = [
  {name: "name1", values:[1,2,3]},
  {name: "name2", values:[3,4,5]}
];
var newObj = {y:[],x:[]}

for (var j=0;j<x.length;j++){
  newObj.x.push([])
  for (var i=0;i<x[j].values.length;i++){
    newObj.x[j].push(x[j].values[i]);
  }
}

newObj.y=y

console.log(newObj)
```

This works for what I am doing, but I am sure it is not even remotely best practices. What would be a more elegant way of organizing the values array from x into the new object with the single value for y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ES6:**

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array of `x` values, and assign `y` using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Note: I use ES6's [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) in the map's callback, but it's not a must. See ES5 version.

```js
const y = 10; 
const x = [
  {name: "name1", values:[1,2,3]},
  {name: "name2", values:[3,4,5]}
];

const result = { 
  y, 
  x: x.map(({ values }) => values) // [...values] if you want a copy of the original values
};

console.log(result);
```

**ES5:**

Use `Array.map()` to get `x` values:

```js
var y = 10; 
var x = [
  {name: "name1", values:[1,2,3]},
  {name: "name2", values:[3,4,5]}
];

var result = { 
  y: y, 
  x: x.map(function(o) {
    return o.values; // values.slice(0) if you want a copy of the original values
  })
};

console.log(result);
```